# Add item from get intent to be post again on different activity like cart shopping Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello i'm beginner on android and i still confuse about adding item that i have on showed list from cardview on recycler view and i want to add it to become cart item but there is always getting problem and force close.

this is my activity about the showing on cardview after been clicked

**TasActivity.java**

```
public class TasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView tvtitle,tvcategory,tvdesc,tvhrg,nama,hrg;
private ImageView img;
private Button btnblnja;
private RatingBar rating;
private SmileRating smile;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tas);

    tvtitle=findViewById(R.id.judultas);
    tvcategory=findViewById(R.id.kategori);
    tvdesc=findViewById(R.id.deskripsi);
    tvhrg = findViewById(R.id.harga);
    img=findViewById(R.id.tasthumbnail);
    btnblnja = findViewById(R.id.tambahbelanja);
    rating = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    smile = findViewById(R.id.smile_rating);

    btnblnja.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent masuk = new Intent(TasActivity.this, KeranjangFragment.class);
            masuk.getStringExtra("Title");
            masuk.getStringExtra("Harga");
            startActivity(masuk);
        }
    });

    Intent intent= getIntent();
    String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("Title");
    String Category = intent.getExtras().getString("Category");
    String Description = intent.getExtras().getString("Description");
    String Harga = intent.getExtras().getString("Harga");
    int image = intent.getExtras().getInt("Img");

    tvtitle.setText(Title);
    tvcategory.setText(Category);
    tvdesc.setText(Description);
    tvhrg.setText(Harga);
    img.setImageResource(image);



}
```

And this is that what i want to be listed for

**KeranjangFragment.java**

```
public class KeranjangFragment extends Fragment {
TextView total;
Button btnpesan;
public KeranjangFragment() {
}

private List<Product> example;
ProductAdapter madapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View krnjg =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keranjang,container,false);

    total = krnjg.findViewById(R.id.vtotal);
    btnpesan = krnjg.findViewById(R.id.btnpsn);
    example = ShoppingCartHelper.getCart();

    RecyclerView rec = krnjg.findViewById(R.id.rc1);
    LinearLayoutManager aw1 =new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    madapter = new ProductAdapter(example,getLayoutInflater(),true);
    madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    rec.setLayoutManager(aw1);

    btnpesan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),CheckoutActivity.class));
        }
    });

    return krnjg;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting on the force close? Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: the error always going on btn click on tasactivity sir

Comment: Ok, but what does the error say. Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: nothing else just error on that click

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call Fragment from Intent... new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class) Add Your KeranjangFragment into an Activity.

Comment: i have try it and made it become like add item but it doesn't work just an error that i clicked it